# Regex - extract all headers from markdown string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, markdown

I am using [gray-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter/) in order to parse .MD files from the file system into a string. The result the parser produces is a string like this:

```
\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n
```

I am now trying to write a regular expression that would extract all the heading text from the string. Headers in markdown start with a # (there can be from 1-6), and in my case always end with a new line.

I've tried using the following regular expression but calling it on my test string returns nothing:

```js
const testString = "\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n"
const HEADING_R = /(?<!#)#{1,6} (.*?)(\\r(?:\\n)?|\\n)/gm;
const headings = HEADING_R.exec(content);

console.log('headings: ', headings);
```

This console logs `headings` as `null` (no matches found). The result that I am looking for would be: `["# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering", "## TL;DR", "## Introduction"]`.

I believe the regular expression is wrong, but have no idea why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`/#{1,6}.+(?=\n)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/n6XQub/1)

- `#{1,6}` ... matches the character `#` at least once or as sequence of maximum 6 equal characters.
- `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators) at least once and as many times as possible (greedy)
- does so until the [*positive lookahead*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) `(?=\n)` matches ...

  - which is ... `\n` ... a newline / line-feed.
- uses the `g`lobal modifier which does match everything.

**Edit**

Having mentioned

> *"matches any character (except for line terminators)"*

thus a regex like ... [`/#{1,6}.+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/n6XQub/2) ... should already do the job (no need for a positive lookahead) for the OP's use case which is ...

> *"Headers in markdown start with a # (there can be from 1-6), **and in my case always end with a new line.**"*

> **The result that I am looking for would be: `["# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering", "## TL;DR", "## Introduction"]`.**

```js
const testString = `\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n`;

// see...[https://regex101.com/r/n6XQub/2]
const regXHeader = /#{1,6}.+/g

console.log(
  testString.match(regXHeader)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Bonus**

Refactoring the above regex into e.g. [`/(?<flag>#{1,6})\s+(?<content>.+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/n6XQub/4) by utilizing [*named capturing groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) alongside with [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task, one could achieve a result like computed by the next provided example code ...

```js
const testString = `\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n`;

// see...[https://regex101.com/r/n6XQub/4]
const regXHeader = /(?<flag>#{1,6})\s+(?<content>.+)/g

console.log(
  Array
    .from(
      testString.matchAll(regXHeader)
    )
    .map(({ groups: { flag, content } }) => ({
      heading: `h${ flag.length }`,
      content,
    }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This does not account for markdown with code blocks that include comments. Failing example: `const testString = "\n## Introduction\n\`\`\`\n# ruby code comment\n\`\`\`\n\n";`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using a literal for the regex and should not double escape the backslash, so you can write it as `(?<!#)#{1,6} (.*?)(\r(?:\n)?|\n)`

You can shorten the pattern capturing what you want and match the trailing newline instead of using a lookbehind assertion.

```
(#{1,6} .*)\r?\n
```

Retrieving all capture group 1 values:

```js
const testString = "\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n"
const HEADING_R = /(#{1,6} .*)\r?\n/g;
const headings = Array.from(testString.matchAll(HEADING_R), m => m[1]);
console.log('headings: ', headings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Corner-case: in many programming languages commented-out code lines start with `#`, the same way as headings do - examples are Bash, Ruby, Python. It looks like this:

```
# run command
npm install
```

An example markdown string representing this would be:

````
const md = "\n# Bash\n\n```\n# nuke OS\nfork()\n```\n"
````

None of the answers posted to-date address this issue. One possible solution is to remove all code blocks beforehand:

````js
const md = "\n# Clean-er ReactJS Code - Conditional Rendering\n\n```bash\n# initialize project via CLI\nnpm create-react-app conditional-rendering\n```\n\n\n## TL;DR\n\nMove render conditions into appropriately named variables. Abstract the condition logic into a function. This makes the render function code a lot easier to understand, refactor, reuse, test, and think about.\n\n## Introduction\n\nConditional rendering is when a logical operator determines what will be rendered. The following code is from the examples in the official ReactJS documentation. It is one of the simplest examples of conditional rendering that I can think of.\n\n"
const headings = md
    .replaceAll(/```(.|\n)+```/gm, "")
    .split("\n")
    .filter(line => line.startsWith("#"))
console.log("Headings:", headings)
````