# Parse MDX file in Next JS?

Tags: next.js

I have an .mdx file I'm importing into a page with Next JS. I'd like to create link fragments to every heading on the page.

So if my default markdown output is:

```
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<p>Text 1</p>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Text 2</p>
```

I need to change it to be:

```
<h2 id="heading-1">Title 1</h2>
<p>Text 1</p>
<h2 id="heading-2">Title 2</h2>
<p>Text 2</p>
```

And I also need know the text and IDs of the headings so I can create the links:

```
<a href="#heading-1">Title 1</a>
<a href="#heading-2">Title 2</a>
```

I could do this manually but I'd like the links to be auto generated. The heading ID's can also be generated and don't need to have human friendly names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Adding an `id` to each `h1`

Adding the `id`s to the headings is pretty simple. You can do this by adding a `components` prop to your `MDXProvider` where you specify how each element should be treated:

```
<MDXRemote {...props.mdx} />
```

Then you can specify that your `h1` components should have an `id` set. You could generate an id if you want, but for this example, we'll just use the `children` as the `id`:

```
const adjustedComponents = {
    h1: (props) => (
      <Heading id={props.children} as="h1" size="lg">
        {props.children}
      </Heading>
    ),
}
```

## Creating the table of contents

Adding links to each heading is a little bit trickier. You could use something like `remark` and [remark-toc](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-toc) for this, but unfortunately that will limit you to **only being able to display the table of contents *within* the Markdown** which is likely not what you want.

To have better control over the table of contents **we'll have to parse the content** and create a custom list of the headings.

```
const headings = await getHeadings(content);
```

[Josh W. Comeau](https://twitter.com/joshwcomeau/status/1334649414812659715?lang=en) came up with a nice way to do the parsing of `h2` and `h3` headings. You will have to modify this if you want to stick with using `h1` headings:

```
export async function getHeadings(source) {
  // Get each line individually, and filter out anything that
  // isn't a heading.
  const headingLines = source.split("\n").filter((line) => {
    return line.match(/^###*\s/);
  });

  // Transform the string '## Some text' into an object
  // with the shape '{ text: 'Some text', level: 2 }'
  return headingLines.map((raw) => {
    const text = raw.replace(/^###*\s/, "");
    // I only care about h2 and h3.
    // If I wanted more levels, I'd need to count the
    // number of #s.
    const level = raw.slice(0, 3) === "###" ? 3 : 2;

    return { text, level };
  });

  return headingLines;
}
```

With that data returned from `getStaticProps`, we can then **pass the headings data in to a `TableOfContents` component** that we can make:

```
<TableOfContents headings={props.headings} />
```

```
const TableOfContents = ({ headings }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Heading as="h3">Table of Contents:</Heading>
      {headings.map((heading) => {
        return (
          <a key={heading.text} href={`#${heading.text}`}>
            {heading.text}
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice that since we used the text of the heading for the `id`s of our headings, we can easily use that same data to set the `href` value for the links: `<a href={`#${heading.text}`}>`. That way the links all go to the correct place.

#### Full example

Here's a full **working example** on CodeSandbox: [image: Edit Next MDX with Table of Contents]

Comment: FYI The npm page for the @mdx-js/runtime library says "warning: this is not the preferred way to use MDX since it introduces a substantial amount of overhead and dramatically increases bundle sizes. It should also not be used with user input that isn’t sandboxed."

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I just updated the CodeSandbox example and the answer to not use `@mdx-js/runtime` anymore

Comment: The only limitation with this approach is that you can't have headings with the same text. For section headings this is OK but if you wanted to have nested headings this could be a problem.

Comment: An even better approach might be to assign IDs to the headings based on the order they appear in the DOM.

Comment: Right, that would be a good improvement

Comment: The getHeadings function is aware of the headings order in the DOM so you could pass index based ID names to TableOfContents for the links. However the adjustedComponents's h1 function isn't aware of this, so I don't see how you could set this type of ID on the headings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

While you definitely could try to use a """real""" parser to do this. I feel like that would be overkill given your use case. If you'd like to give it a try, I recommend [remark-mdx](https://mdxjs.com/packages/remark-mdx/#syntax-tree).

Alternatively, I would just use a simple regular expression system. I won't write the code for you but here's how I would do it:

```
headings = []
while(find(header regex) is not -1):
    index = find(header regex)
    replace(index, <h2, <h2 id="header-{headings.length}")
    headings.push(
        {
            id: "header-{headings.length}",
            text: evaluate(header regex).capture_group[0]
        }
    )
```

For the regex to find these headers, I would try something like [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801756/regex-extract-all-headers-from-markdown-string). I also recommend you read up on capture groups [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences).

I hope this is detailed enough. If you have any more questions just post a comment under this question.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Andrew Hulterstrom's answer I found a solution I prefer slightly. MDX allows HTML so I'm detecting the heading in markdown and replacing it with an HTML heading with an index based ID. This has the advantage that you can have multiple headings with the same text.

I'm passing an array of headings to the page. Using the index in the array I can create the link fragments needed.

```
import {GetStaticProps} from "next";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import {serialize} from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";

export async function getStaticProps(props: GetStaticProps) {
    const root = process.cwd();
    const folderPath = path.join(root, "pages/my-post");
    const filePath = path.join(folderPath, "my-post-content.mdx");
    const fawFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const { content } = matter(fawFile);

    let headingsI = 0;
    const headings: string[] = [];

    const contentModified = content
        .split("\n")
        .map((item) => {
            if (item.startsWith("### ")) {
                headingsI++;
                const headingText = item.replace("### ", "");
                headings.push(headingText);
                return `<h3 id="h3-${headingsI}">${headingText}</h3>\n`;
            }
            return item;
        })
        .join("\n");

    const mdxSource = await serialize(contentModified);

    return {
        props: {
            content: mdxSource,
            headings,
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: your solution looks really good but it throws 
```Expected a closing tag for `<h2>` (2:1-2:15) before the end of `paragraph```

Possibly, there is some mess up in formating